# How to convert Boolean array to Single Boolean or Single String in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have problem converting a boolean array like `{true,true}` or `{}`.
The result should be `true` and `null`, respectively.

What I have currently is `{true,}`, `{true,true}` and `{}`.
But I need the result as `true`, `true` and `null`. Please help.

My query is:

```
select t, array_agg(distinct abc) as abc
from tbl
```

I want to convert `array_agg` to a single boolean or string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `array_agg`. Use `bool_or` instead:

```
SELECT t, bool_or(abc) AS abc
FROM tbl;
```

Comment: Yes this is fine.Thanks